# What should the service layer return to the controller when validating data in service layer for a .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a small car API that is made up of a controller, service and repository I want to validate the data from within the service layer and return the 200, 404 or 400 with a little message saying what the problem is from the service. In other words, I want to move all the logic from the controller to the service layer.

How can I return a status code and if it's an error what caused the error, from the service layer to the controller?

API Controller method:

```
[HttpGet("GetById/{Id:int}", Name = "GetCar")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

public IActionResult GetById(int Id)
{
    if (Id < 1)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CarIdIsZero", "Car Id Must Not Be Less Than One !");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var car = _db.Car.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);

    if (car == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CarNotFound", "Car was not found !");
        return NotFound(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok(car);

}
```

Service Layer Method:

```
public IActionResult GetById(int carId)
{
    return;
}
```

Repository Layer Method:

```
public Car? GetById(int carId)
{
    return _db.Car.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == carId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid passing back an `IActionResult` from your service as this tightly couples your service to the particular action in your controller. Instead we have a few of ways to pass back errors that can then be handled in the controller.

1. Exceptions - You should really try to use these sparingly, as they come with a performance overhead and can cause a debugging headache (it's not obvious how far up the call stack you have to go to find where the exception is going to be caught). That being said, it's reasonable to catch any exceptions thrown by your repository in the controller and return an appropriate `5xx` response.
2. Result Wrapper - You could create a `CarResult` class which contains your original `Car` object along with a list of errors and a Boolean indicating success, i.e. `Success = !Errors.Any();`. This works particularly well for validation where you may want to add several errors, then in your controller send back an appropriate `BadRequest` with all your errors.
3. Out Params - Similar to the above, except without the need for an additional class. You could change the signature of your service method to `public bool TryGetById(int carId, out Car car, out List<string> errors)` where the bool result indicates success. So based off this book you know whether the `car` or `errors` param will be populated.
4. Discriminated Unions - This will require quite a lot of extra boilerplate code or an additional package, so may be overkill. That being said it is what I use in enterprise applications if possible, as it's essentially a Result Wrapper on steroids - your service can dynamically pass back a `Car` object for success or an `Error` object for validation failure, or an `Exception` if one is thrown by your repository.

In any of these options you'd map the result (success, error, or exception) to the appropriate `IActionResult` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The main goal of your service layer is to interact with your provided database and execute the busniess logic(data manipulation etc).

now regarding what should the service layer returns, the service layer then returns the result to the controller layer, which formats the response and returns it to the client.

This means that whatever operation your service perform if it got successful it will return the result e.g.: User.

But if something happened it'll return the error and based on that return you decided what message you have to send to the client.

Comment: When using the repository pattern the service layer delegates database interactions to the repository. The service layer just handles the logic that applies to the data such as validation.

Answer (score 0):

well, as a general rule, your operations should either succeed or fail miserably :)
That being said, one option would be to start by implementing a *validation* step on the input. Here you could either:

- return some kind of `ValidationResult` and then build a `BadRequestResponse` manually
- use data annotations on the incoming DTO
- throw an `ArgumentException`, capture it and return a `BadRequestResponse`

These are all viable solutions, although I would probably avoid using exceptions to control the flow.

Now, supposing that the validation is successful, you have the actual operation to execute. As stated before, this should either succeed or fail as quickly as possible (with a very loud exception).
Exceptions would result in a 500 error returned to the client. And this is fine since ideally, the fault is of your service, not on the caller's side.

In the case of queries, you can either have the result or a null (or a *NullObject*). At this point, you just have to return either a `OkResult` or a `NotFoundResult`.